# Paragraphs in textarea

Tags: php, textarea, paragraph

I have a form that has a textarea in it. How would I make new lines in the textarea appear as new paragraphs when I echo out the submitted textarea value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```php
<?php
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

    $newarr = explode("\n", $textarea);

    foreach($newarr as $str) {

        echo "<p>".$str."</p>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: not me - now **you** don't have that issue. I did not asked the question, I just pointed about weak place in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function:

```
<?php 

echo nl2br($_POST['textarea']);

?>
```

It will print `<br>` all newlines

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<p>' . preg_replace("~[\r\n]+~", '</p><p>', $textarea) . '</p>';
```